# Position not working?

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-manipulation, index

I have the list:

```
myList={0,0,0,a,b,c,0,0,d}
```

I need to find the positions of all elements that are non-zero. I do like this:

```
Position[myList,x_ /; x != 0]
```

The output is `{}`. Meanwhile, the output for:

```
In= Position[myList,x_ /; x == 0]
Out= {{1}, {2}, {3}, {7}, {8}}
```

I don't understand what is going on. `a`,`b`,`c` and `d` are symbolic variables.

Comment: `Position[myList,Except[0], {1}, Heads -> False]`

Comment: check out `a != 0` Does this return `True`?

Comment: All work, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is indeed somewhat confusing when you are new to Mathematica.

In Mathematica, `==` stands for mathematical equality.  Thus `a == 0` does not evaluate to either `True` or to `False` until `a` is replaced by a numerical value.  `a` is considered to be a variable that may or may not be zero.

A pattern like `x_ /; condition` will only match if `condition` is explicitly `True`.  Anything else than `True`, including things that are not literally `False`, will cause the match to fail.

So what can you do here?

You can use `===` which tests if two expressions are structurally the same.  But note that `0 === 0.` is `False`, as these two values are not identical (even if mathematically they're the same).  With `===` you'd have to separately test for both `0` and `0.`, which is inconvenient and error prone.  The same goes for `Except`.

Here I would rely on `TrueQ`, which can turn things that are not literally the symbol `True` into `False`.

```
Position[myList, x_ /; Not@TrueQ[x == 0], {1}, Heads -> False]
```

Additionally I used a level specification to look only at the first level, and asked not to test the head (which is `List`).